# How to extend SimpleJpaRepository and use getQueryHints()

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way to extend from 
[`org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/2.3.x/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java) and use its `protected QueryHints getQueryHints()` method where the extending implementation is not located in package `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support`?

The problem is, that the interface [`org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QueryHints`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/2.3.x/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/QueryHints.java)s visibility is package protected.

I am not sure,

- if I'm doing something wrong,
- did not know a trick or workaround
- is it just an issue of Spring Data? (Then I would file a bug report, but will fist ask if I am wrong?)

I use Spring-Data-JPA 2.3.0 (the code is the same for 2.3.1) you can see the important snippets below:

```
package org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support;
public class SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements JpaRepositoryImplementation<T, ID> {
    ...
    protected QueryHints getQueryHints() {
        return metadata == null ? NoHints.INSTANCE : DefaultQueryHints.of(entityInformation, metadata);
    }
    ...
}
```

```
package org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support;
interface QueryHints extends Iterable<Entry<String, Object>> {...}   //this is not public!
```

---

**Background** */ why I came up with this problem / example*

I try to implement a more complex `buildOrder` logic, and therefore need to override `SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery`

```
public class MySimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> {
...
    /* same as SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery but with a different toOrders invocation */
    @Override
    protected <S extends T> TypedQuery<S> getQuery(@Nullable Specification<S> spec, Class<S> domainClass, Sort sort) {

        CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<S> query = builder.createQuery(domainClass);

        Root<S> root = applySpecificationToCriteria(spec, domainClass, query);
        query.select(root);

        if (sort.isSorted()) {
            /* this invoke my myToOrders instead of static QueryUtils.toOrders method */
            query.orderBy(myToOrders(sort, root, builder)); 
        }

        return applyRepositoryMethodMetadata(entityManager.createQuery(query));
    }

    /* because the methods
     *   - SimpleJpaRepository.applySpecificationToCriteria and 
     *   - SimpleJpaRepository.applyRepositoryMethodMetadata 
     * (that invoked by) getQuery are private I need to copy them.
     * 
     * Then SimpleJpaRepository.applyRepositoryMethodMetadata requries the private method
     *    - SimpleJpaRepository.applyQueryHints
     * (see below)
     */

    /* I need to copy the method applyQueryHints because it is private */
    private void applyQueryHints(Query query) {
        for (Entry<String, Object> hint : getQueryHints().withFetchGraphs(this.entityManager)) {
            query.setHint(hint.getKey(), hint.getValue());
        }
    }
...
}
```

I do not like to copy the methods, but I will accept it. But what troubles me, is that the invocation of `getQueryHints()` requires that `MySimpleJpaRepository` is located in `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support` because of the return type (`QueryHints`) visibility.

Answer (score 1):

I also had to deal with this and, following some researches, I ended up with:

```
/**
 * Apply the query hints.
 * @param query the {@link JPAQuery} instance
 * @param forCount whether is for count
 */
private void applyHints(JPAQuery<T> query, boolean forCount) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> hint : asMap(forCount).entrySet()) {
        query.setHint(hint.getKey(), hint.getValue());
    }

}

private Map<String, Object> asMap(boolean forCount) {
    Map<String, Object> hints = new HashMap<>();
    if (getRepositoryMethodMetadata() != null) {
        if (forCount) {
            hints.putAll(getRepositoryMethodMetadata().getQueryHintsForCount());
        } else {
            hints.putAll(getRepositoryMethodMetadata().getQueryHints());
        }
        hints.putAll(getFetchGraphs());
    }
    return hints;
}

private Map<String, Object> getFetchGraphs() {
    return getRepositoryMethodMetadata().getEntityGraph().map(entityGraph -> Jpa21Utils
            .tryGetFetchGraphHints(entityManager, getEntityGraph(entityGraph), entityInformation.getJavaType()))
            .orElse(Collections.emptyMap());
}

private JpaEntityGraph getEntityGraph(EntityGraph entityGraph) {
    String fallbackName = entityInformation.getEntityName() + "." + getRepositoryMethodMetadata().getMethod()
            .getName();
    return new JpaEntityGraph(entityGraph, fallbackName);
}
```

The above code is heavily inspired (if not a direct copy) from the available implementations.

The key method is `getRepositoryMethodMetadata()`.

As you can see, it takes care of all possible metadata, including fetch graphs.

Of course, the method you'll have to use is `applyHints(JPAQuery<T> query, boolean forCount)`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of this issue is to replace `getQueryHints()` with `getRepositoryMethodMetadata().getQueryHints()` in your class extending `SimpleJpaRepository`